# Must be initialized error in val variable

Tags: android, kotlin

Following code report `property must be initialized or be abstract` error.

```
// MyApi.kt
interface MyApi {

    ...
}

// MyFetch.kt
class MyFetch {

    private val myApi: MyApi  // <- this line

    ...
}
```

It can use `lateinit` statement in mutable variable, but how should I predefined in val?

Comment: Check this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html

Comment: Put it in the constructor so it can be passed in the the class is initialized.

Comment: @Tenfour04 is it mean I need using myApi in `init {}` construct?

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: @ccd it means you need to have an implementation of interface being on the myApi property in order to initialize MyFetch class?, or be some sort of delegated.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use lazy, or make it nullable

```
private val myApi: MyApi? = null
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to initialize the variable on the time of object creation in the variable declairation itself or in the `init{}` block, since there is no preinit null type in the Kotlin.

And since your variable is `val` not `var` you cannot set it after created so there's no point of creating the variable.

If you meant to initialize the variable later on but only once, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445081/11377112
This is done by delegation like this:

```
class InitOnceProperty<T> : ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {

    private object EMPTY

    private var value: Any? = EMPTY

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        if (value == EMPTY) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Value isn't initialized")
        } else {
            return value as T
        }
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        if (this.value != EMPTY) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Value is initialized")
        }
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

Now you can delegate the variable by the delegate

```
var property: Int by InitOnceProperty()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Separation of Concerns design pattern would favor passing a value to the constructor. So some other class that instantiates your MyFetch class would also instantiate your MyApi instance and pass it to the constructor:

```
class MyClass(val myApi: MyApi){

}

//Some higher level class:
val myAPI = object: MyApi { //... }
val myClass = MyClass(myApi)
```

But you can also just initialize it from within the class. This would make sense if MyApi is tightly coupled to the behavior of MyClass:

```
class MyClass {

    val myApi = object: MyApi { //... }

}

// or

class MyClass {

    val myApi: MyApi

    init {
        myApi = object: MyApi { //... }
    }
}
```

In any of the three cases, a value of read-only `val` property has to be assigned in either the constructor, inline with the declaration, or in an `init` block. The only other option is to use a property delegate.