How to initialize AndroidViewModel with parameters from Intent.getExtras in onCreate and make instance available to Activity as class val
I'm having a scope crisis.  I want to both instantiate a AndroidViewModel from extras passed to onCreate via Intent and also have it available as a val scoped to the entire class.  Here is some code that I hope explains what I'm after.  How can I achieve this?
    fun onScan(
        scan: String
    ) {
        val kitID = scan
        sendKitReserveRequest(
            kitID = kitID,
            shipmentID = viewModel.shipmentID,    // <------- viewModel out of scope
            onAlert = { title, message ->
                dialogTitle.value = title         // <------- dialogTitle is MutableState class scoped
                dialogMessage.value = message     // <------- dialogMessage is MutableState class scoped
                showMessageDialog.value = true
            },
            onResponse = { response ->
                viewModel.reserveKit(    // <------- viewModel out of scope
                    kitID = kitID,
                    shipmentID = viewModel.shipmentID    // <------- viewModel out of scope
                )
            },
            showProgressDialog = showProgressDialog
        )
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created.  */
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if(intent.hasExtra(JSON.SHIPMENT_ID)) {
            val viewModel by viewModels<ShipmentViewModel>(
                factoryProducer = {
                    object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                            return ShipmentViewModel(
                                application = application,
                                shipmentID = intent.getStringExtra(JSON.SHIPMENT_ID) ?: "0"
                            ) as T
                        }
                    }
                }
            )

            setContent {
                ConceptualSystemsTheme {
                    Scaffold(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                    ) { scaffoldPadding ->
                        MainLayout(
                            scaffoldPadding,
                            viewModel
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            //shipmentID is required.  eject from Activity if it is not available.
            finish()
        }
    }

I would like for the viewModel instance to be an immutable val available to the entire class, but the value comes from within onCreate via the Intent extras.  Is it possible to achieve this without making a the ShipmentViewModel a lateinit var?

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443167/kotlin-lateinit-to-val-or-alternatively-a-var-that-can-set-once

by viewModels at the activity level already automatically provides intent extras through the ViewModel's SavedStateHandle, you don't need a custom factory for that. Is there a reason you aren't using that?

It turns out that the original code was fine when the ViewModel was defined in the class scope.  by viewModels returns a Lazy wrapped value which is only instantiated the first time it's used, so as long as the Intent value is read in onCreate before the first access to the ViewModel, then the correct value will be used as the ViewModel parameter.
    private val shipmentID: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf("0")
    private val viewModel: ShipmentViewModel by viewModels<ShipmentViewModel>(
        factoryProducer = {
            object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                    return ShipmentViewModel(
                        application = application,
                        shipmentID = intent.getStringExtra(JSON.SHIPMENT_ID) ?: "0"
                    ) as T
                }
            }
        }
    )

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if(intent.hasExtra(JSON.SHIPMENT_ID)) {
            shipmentID.value = intent.getStringExtra(JSON.SHIPMENT_ID) ?: "0"   //set value which we will pass to the viewModel

            setContent {
                ConceptualSystemsTheme {
                    Scaffold(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                    ) { scaffoldPadding ->
                        MainLayout(            // viewModel will be instantiated inside MainLayout when it is first accessed, so the correct value will be passed at that time as it has already been set above.
                            scaffoldPadding
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            //shipmentID is required.  eject from Activity if it is not available.
            finish()
        }
    }

